# seo pagination help to avoid duplication

Tags: pagination, seo

Suppose i have article submission site
I have more than 1000 article and daily updated and added new

***i have three parameter connected with article***

> 1. category
> 2. tag
> 3. author

***and my structure of pagination like***

> category wise articles
>   =>site.com/category/{category_name}
>
> tag wise articles
>   =>site.com/tag/{tag_name}
>
> particular author posted articles
>   =>site.com/{author_name}/{article}

All page show article as pagination.
How can apply pagination for above all links
Need Suggestion for

```
 1. url structure like. ?page=number or /page/number
 2. How can i avoid duplication because there is full chance.
 3. any suggestion regarding html tag for seo
 4. or i can improve this structure
 5. and which one best url for displaying content /article/slug or any??
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1):

Just open page and - View Page Source then find line

link rel="canonical" href="http://yourwebsite/

if you have it everything will be fine.

This article can help :

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

But if you have duplicate content from other sites you must add line :

META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"